# How to Get All Nodes With a Specific Value?

Tags: java, cytoscape

I am just began to develop cytoscape plugin. I am trying to hide all nodes which has "pronaliz:status" statement in its "shared name" column. I saw the link below and i tryed it but could not make it. It is not hiding any node.

http://wiki.cytoscape.org/Cytoscape_3/AppDeveloper/Cytoscape_3_App_Cookbook#How_to_get_all_the_nodes_with_a_specific_attribute_value.3F

Here is my code. I am just warming up to Cytoscape classes and methods. Anyone can help me please?

```
public class MenuAction extends AbstractCyAction {
private final CyAppAdapter adapter;

public MenuAction(CyAppAdapter adapter) {
    super("Hide Status",
            adapter.getCyApplicationManager(),
            "network",
            adapter.getCyNetworkViewManager());
    this.adapter = adapter;
    setPreferredMenu("Select");
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    final CyApplicationManager manager = adapter.getCyApplicationManager();
    final CyNetworkView networkView = manager.getCurrentNetworkView();
    final CyNetwork network = networkView.getModel();
    final CyTable table = network.getDefaultNodeTable();

    final Set<CyNode> nodes = new HashSet<CyNode>();
    final Collection<CyRow> matchingRows = table.getMatchingRows("shared name", ":status");
    final String primaryKeyColname = table.getPrimaryKey().getName();

    for (final CyRow row : matchingRows) {
        final Long nodeId = row.get(primaryKeyColname, Long.class);
        if (nodeId == null)
            continue;
        final CyNode node = network.getNode(nodeId);
        if (node == null)
            continue;
        nodes.add(node);
    }

    for(CyNode node: nodes){
        networkView.getNodeView(node).setVisualProperty(BasicVisualLexicon.NODE_VISIBLE, false);
    }
    networkView.updateView();
}
```

}

Comment: This question looks legitimate to me.  Someone's voted to close the question.  If anyone thinks the question isn't clear, please let everyone know how you think the question could be improved.